# WatchOS: Inserting pages in page-based navigation

Tags: navigation, watchos-2, watchos

I'm using `-[WKInterfaceController presentControllerWithNames:contexts:]` to modally present a dynamically-created set of pages. There may be occasions where I want to insert a page in the set of pages while they are visible. Is this possible, or is the set of pages fixed once visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I have devised for this.

```
/*
MyInterfaceController - class within the set of pages
*/
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)context;
    self.uuid = [dict valueForKey:@"uuid"];
    self.jumpuuid = [dict valueForKey:@"jumpuuid"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkBecomeCurrentPage:) name:@"checkBecomeCurrentPage" object:nil];
}

- (void)checkBecomeCurrentPage:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSString *checkUUID = (NSString*)notification.object;

    if ([self.uuid isEqualToString:checkUUID]) {
        [self becomeCurrentPage];
    }
}

- (void)didAppear {
    [super didAppear];

    if (self.jumpuuid) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"checkBecomeCurrentPage" object:self.jumpuuid];
    }
}

- (IBAction)addPageButtonAction {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addPageNotification" object:self];
}

#warning Populate this with the names and contexts for the set of pages when initially displaying them. It is used for inserting pages later
+ (NSMutableDictionary*)namesAndContextsForCurrentlyDisplayedPage {
    static NSMutableDictionary *dict = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    });
    return dict;
}

+ (void)addPageWithPresentingController:(WKInterfaceController *)presentingController requestingInterfaceController:(MyInterfaceController *)requestingInterfaceController {
    NSMutableArray *contexts = [[[MyInterfaceController namesAndContextsForCurrentlyDisplayedPages] objectForKey:@"contexts"] mutableCopy];

    NSInteger requestingInterfaceControllerIndex = -1;

    for (NSDictionary *dict in contexts) {
        if ([[dict valueForKey:@"uuid"] isEqualToString:requestingInterfaceController.uuid]) {
            requestingInterfaceControllerIndex = [contexts indexOfObject:dict];
        }
    }

    if (requestingSetInterfaceControllerIndex == -1) {
        #warning Display an error that the position of the current page could not be established
    }
    else {
        NSInteger insertIndex = requestingInterfaceControllerIndex + 1;

        NSMutableArray *names = [[[MyInterfaceController namesAndContextsForCurrentlyDisplayedPages] objectForKey:@"names"] mutableCopy];
        [names insertObject:@"MyInterfaceController" atIndex:insertIndex];

        NSString *newUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
        NSDictionary *newDict = @{@"uuid": newUUID};

        [contexts insertObject:newdict atIndex:insertIndex];

        NSMutableDictionary *firstDict = [contexts.firstObject mutableCopy];
        [firstDict setValue:newUUID forKey:@"jumpuuid"];
        [contexts replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:firstDict];

        [[MyInterfaceController namesAndContextsForCurrentlyDisplayedPages] setValue:names forKey:@"names"];
        [[MyInterfaceController namesAndContextsForCurrentlyDisplayedPages] setValue:contexts forKey:@"contexts"];

        [presentingController dismissController];
        [presentingController presentControllerWithNames:names contexts:contexts];
    }
}
```

-

```
/*
MyParentInterfaceController - the controller which originally presented the set of pages
*/

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addPage:) name:@"addPageNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)addPage:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [MyInterfaceController addPageWithPresentingController:self requestingInterfaceController:notification.object];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have devised a method to achieve this, but it's messy. A better solution would be a considerable improvement.

1. Each `WKInterfaceController` in the group of pages has a `UUID` property which is assigned using its context and stored during `awakeWithContext:`
2. The `WKInterfaceController` which presents the group of pages retains the arrays of `WKInterfaceController` names and contexts before presenting them
3. When one of the pages needs to insert/delete pages from the set, it posts a notification back to the presenting `WKInterfaceController`
4. The presenting `WKInterfaceController` makes the changes required in its retained arrays of `WKInterfaceController` names and contexts
5. The presenting `WKInterfaceController` dismisses the current group of pages and then re-presents them using the updated name/context arrays
6. The presenting `WKInterfaceController` posts a notification which is observed by all of the pages, including the `UUID` for the new page as the notification object. The notification triggers the pages to check their own `UUID` against the one sent in the notification object. If the notification matches, then that interface controller calls `becomeCurrentPage`

I haven't actually tested this, but it's the only method I can think of that might work. It would be ugly though, as you would see the current page disappear, then the first page appear, and then the new page animate into view. Not great from a user experience perspective, but I can't think of any other way since Apple doesn't give us any methods to insert pages.